# PHP выделение блоков из текста по ключу

Tags: php, php7

Доброе время суток!
Требуется помощь, есть данные которые приходят из формы, пример данных:

"сургут-6454/6466-4353/4354-сургут"

Как можно отправлять символы в массив которые между "-"? в таком виде:
Array ([0] => сургут [2] => 6454/6466 [3] => 4353/4354 [4] =>сургут);
понял как преобразовывать всю строку через explode(). но получается каждый символ отдельно

Comment: В чем проблема `explode`? Или вам нужнен прям цикл посимвольного занесения в массив?

Comment: В смысле ваш вариант подходит, просто я не понял как можно использовать разделение что бы запись в массив происходила именно кусками! Большое спасибо!) Аж стыдно что ответ оказался так прост) Я уже полтора часа с алгоритмами воюю)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php

$text = "сургут-6454/6466-4353/4354-сургут";

$array = explode('-', $text);

var_dump($array);
```

Результат:

```
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  string(12) "сургут"
  [1]=>
  string(9) "6454/6466"
  [2]=>
  string(9) "4353/4354"
  [3]=>
  string(12) "сургут"
}
```

---

Ссылки:

[PHP SandBox Online](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/966209d04cfab5ed6b61133ac5154b95a4fd4cd0)

[PHP Explode](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.explode.php)